# .htaccess - Rewrite folder to domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have page created with WordPress. I am using WPML to translate my page and everything is created in other domains: domain.pl for Polish, domain.com for English etc.

I saw in google index that my page has also domain.pl/en pages indexed. Not much but I need to redirect them.
Is there any posibility to redirect

> www.domain.pl/en to www.domain.com
>
> www.domain.pl/en/post to www.domain.com/post

In general:

> www.domain.pl/en/.../.../... to www.domain.com/.../.../...

with rewrite rule in my .htaccess?

I will be grateful for your help.

Also sorry if something I do wrong - this is my first post here.

Comment: I am trying this:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^en$ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^en(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>`

And I think it will work... hope so it is good redirect

Comment: Did you try this https://wpml.org/forums/topic/language-subfolder-redirect/?
This is about language subfolder redirection. Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: @OwaisAlam my solution work as I need when I go [http://example.pl/en](http://example.pl/en) without slash on the end of URL.
When I have  [http://example.pl/en/](http://example.pl/en/) with slash on the end of URL I am redirected right but with two slashes // on the end of URL: I get something like this: [http://example.com//](http://example.com//)